# Checkout Is not working properly in Html webpage

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem in checkout, i included add to cart code in my webpage and it is working but the checkout button is not working. What is the code or link that i should add in the webpage .The java script i am using is     http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/minicart/3.0.6/minicart.min.js
    and the code in webpage is

```
          <form action="" method="post">
            <fieldset>
                <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart" />
                <input type="hidden" name="add" value="1" />
                <input type="hidden" name="business" value="example@minicartjs.com" />
                <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="MAVJ10015" />
                <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="10.00" />

                <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="INR" />
                <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.minicartjs.com/?success" />
                <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://www.minicartjs.com/?cancel" />
                <input type="image" name="submit" src="images/add to cart.png" class="button" style="margin-left: 73px; margin-top: 6px; height: 21px;"/>         
            </fieldset>
        </form>
```

Comment: the button click is not able to submit the form,

Comment: then what code is to be inserted for it

Comment: add value for action in form.
$( "#button_id" ).click(function() {
  $( "#form_id" ).submit();
});

Comment: but it is not working can you give another suggestion

Comment: Actually i am using paypal  checkout button, and  i just renamed it as submit button and so  i kept the javascript link.The entire added cart should go to mail when the submit button is clicked.How i should write php code for this?

Answer (score 0):

here i am using php to process the post data.
the changes i made are

1. given id to form
2. given id to button

submit the cart using the jsvascript

```
$( "#button_id" ).click(function() { $( "#form_id" ).submit(); });
```

and php code to process the data.

```
<?php
   if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
       print_r($_POST);
       echo "</br></br>";
       echo "business : ". $_POST['business'];
       }       
?>
```

the entire code is here

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <form action="" method="post" id="form_id">
         <fieldset>
            <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart" />
            <input type="hidden" name="add" value="1" />
            <input type="hidden" name="business" value="example@minicartjs.com" />
            <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="MAVJ10015" />
            <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="10.00" />
            <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="INR" />
            <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.minicartjs.com/?success" />
            <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://www.minicartjs.com/?cancel" />
            <input id="button_id" type="image" name="submit" value="submit" src="images/add to cart.png" class="button" style="margin-left: 73px; margin-top: 6px; height: 21px;" />  
         </fieldset>
      </form>
   </body>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      $( "#button_id" ).click(function() { $( "#form_id" ).submit(); });
   </script>
</html>
<?php
   if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
       print_r($_POST);
       echo "</br></br>";
       echo "business : ". $_POST['business'];
       }       
?>
```

Comment: my page is saved as html,can i give php code in same page or i have to rename the page as php

Comment: write php code in different page. give the page path in action attribute of form

Comment: for paypal you can go through the link http://technoblogging.com/blog/How-to-use-Paypal-pro-%28Dodirect-payment%29-in-php/60#sthash.h1n9ioXz.dpuf

Comment: The checkout page is displaying like this.What is the mistake i have done?..........................Array ( [quantity_1] => 5 [item_name_1] => MCCD101 [amount_1] => 105 [shipping_1] => undefined [shipping2_1] => undefined [quantity_2] => 1 [item_name_2] => MCCD103 [amount_2] => 83 [shipping_2] => undefined [shipping2_2] => undefined [cmd] => _cart [upload] => 1 [bn] => MiniCart_AddToCart_WPS_US [business] => info@domainname.com [currency_code] => INR [return] => http://www.minicartjs.com/?success [cancel_return] => http://www.minicartjs.com/?cancel )